# Fade bars in a stack diagram on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm using d3 to compare 2 datasets in a stack layout. Everything looks great except that when I mouseover a particular column, I'd like all the **other** columns to fade to .2 opacity. At this point I can get all the columns to fade, however I'm having trouble keeping the particular column my mouse is hovering over solid. Here's the code to change the bars on mousover & mouseout:

```
var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")

 // Rect initialization code here....    

.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    // make all bars opaque
    fade(.2);
    })
.on("mouseout", function() {
    fade(1);
    });
```

and here's the fade function:

```
function fade(opacity) {
    d3.selectAll("rect")
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", opacity);
};
```

So basically I need a filter function to select everything but the rect my mouse is highlighting. D3 does have one, but I'm a bit confused on how to implement this for my situation. Any help?

**Update**

I slightly updated Lars Kotthoff's answer and got this to work. As this is a stack chart I also wanted to select both bars in the same row. Here's my code for any future users:

```
function fade(opacity, selectedBar) {
    d3.selectAll("rect")
        .filter(function(d, i) { return selectedBar !== d && selectedBar.x !== d.x; })
        .transition()
        .style("opacity", opacity);
};
```

And then in the main section I just passed the opacity level and selected element to the fade function:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
        fade(.4, d);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the datum bound to the current node to filter it:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  // make all bars opaque
  fade(.2, d);
})
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
  fade(1, d);
});

function fade(opacity, d) {
  d3.selectAll("rect")
    .filter(function(e) { return e !== d; })
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", opacity);
}
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but when I try it d !== d returns false for every single element...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to declare that as an argument -- answer updated.