# Fade out all bars on bar chart on mouseover (except the one my cursor is on top of)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get all bars to fade out on mouseover except the one my cursor is on top of——that's the the one I want to highlight by keeping it full opacity. So far I've been able to get all bars to fade out on mouseover and back in on mouseout. Here's the code. Maybe the filter function isn't working?

Thank you!

```
const filmPermits = await d3.json(
    'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/tg4x-b46p.json',
);

const byZipCode = d3.rollup(
    filmPermits,
    (v) => v.length,
    (d) => d['zipcode_s'],
);

const WIDTH = 1400;
const HEIGHT = 600;

const svg = app.append('svg');
// svg.style('border', '1px solid red');
svg.style('background', '#FCF9F5');
svg.attr('width', WIDTH);
svg.attr('height', HEIGHT + 100);
svg.attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${WIDTH} ${HEIGHT}`);

const x_scale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(Array.from(byZipCode.keys()))
    // {11217, 10013, 10014, 11222, ...}
    .range([0, WIDTH]);

const largestValue = d3.max(Array.from(byZipCode.values()));

const y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, largestValue]).range([0, HEIGHT]);

var colorScale = d3
    .scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(Array.from(byZipCode.keys()))
    .range(['#7A3E65', '#A84448', '#E9A178']);

const bars = svg
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(byZipCode)
    .join('rect')
    // d looks like ['Brooklyn', 10]
    .attr('x', (d) => x_scale(d[0]))
    .attr('y', (d) => HEIGHT - y_scale(d[1]))
    .attr('width', () => x_scale.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', (d) => y_scale(d[1]))
    .attr('fill', (d) => colorScale(d[0]))
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
        // make all bars semi-opaque
        fade(0.2, d);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
        fade(1, d);
    });

const text = svg
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(byZipCode)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .text((item) => {
        return item + ' times';
    })
    .attr('x', (d) => x_scale(d[0]))
    .attr('y', (d) => HEIGHT - y_scale(d[1]) - 10)
    .style('font-family', 'Monospace')
    .attr('fill', (d) => colorScale(d[0]))
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
        // make all bars semi-opaque
        fade(0.2, d);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
        fade(1, d);
    });

// function fade(opacity, d) {
//  d3.selectAll('rect')
//      .filter(function (e) {
//          return e !== d;
//      })
//      .transition()
//      .style('opacity', opacity);

//  d3.selectAll('text')
//      .filter(function (e) {
//          return e !== d;
//      })
//      .transition()
//      .style('opacity', opacity);
// }

function fade(opacity, selectedBar) {
    d3.selectAll('rect')
        .filter(function (d, i) {
            return selectedBar !== d && selectedBar.x !== d.x;
        })
        .transition()
        .style('opacity', opacity);
    d3.selectAll('text')
        .filter(function (d, i) {
            return selectedBar !== d && selectedBar.x !== d.x;
        })
        .transition()
        .style('opacity', opacity);
}
```

Used this to help me get mouseover and mouseout to work generally:

[Fade bars in a stack diagram on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044845/fade-bars-in-a-stack-diagram-on-mouseover)

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this, specially avoiding `d3.selectAll` every time the event fires, but let's focus on your question alone:

Your datum is not a primitive, therefore you cannot do a comparison like `selectedBar !== d`. Also, you don't seem to have a `x` property in the datum. Thus, choosing a unique value (the one used by the x scale), your filter should be:

```
.filter(function (d, i) {
    return selectedBar[0] !== d[0];
})
```

Comment: Switching out my filter function for this one didn't quite work; does anyone have any other ideas I could try?